# Elasticsearch scan and scroll - add to new index

Tags: bash, http, elasticsearch, kibana-4

Elasticsearch and command line programming noobie question.

I have elasticsearch set up locally  on my computer and want to pull documents from a server that uses a different version of es using the scan and scroll api and add them into my index. I am having trouble figuring out how to do this with the bulk api for es.

Right now in my testing phase I am just pulling a few documents from the server using the following code (which works):

```
   http MY-OLD-ES.com:9200/INDEX/TYPE/_search?size=1000 | jq   .hits.hits[] -c | while read x; do id="`echo "$x" | jq -r ._id`"; index="`echo "$x" | jq -r ._index`"; type="`echo "$x" | jq -r ._type`"; doc="`echo "$x" | jq ._source`"; http put "localhost:9200/junk-$index/$type/$id" <<<"$doc"; done
```

Any tips on how scan and scroll works (noob and a bit confused). So far know I can scroll and get a scroll id, but I'm unclear what to do with the scroll id.
If I call

```
http get http://MY-OLD-ES.com:9200/my_index/_search?scroll=1m&search_type=scan&size=10
```

I'll receive a scroll id. Can this be piped in and parsed the same way? Additionally, I believe I'll need a while loop to tell it to keep requesting. How exactly should I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [scan and scroll](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html) documentation explains it pretty clearly. After you get the `scroll_id` (a long base64 encoded string), you pass it in with the body of the request. With curl the request would looks something like this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://MY-OLD-ES.com:9200/_search/scroll?scroll=1m' -d '
c2Nhbjs1OzExODpRNV9aY1VyUVM4U0NMd2pjWlJ3YWlBOzExOTpRNV9aY1VyUVM4U0 
NMd2pjWlJ3YWlBOzExNjpRNV9aY1VyUVM4U0NMd2pjWlJ3YWlBOzExNzpRNV9aY1Vy
UVM4U0NMd2pjWlJ3YWlBOzEyMDpRNV9aY1VyUVM4U0NMd2pjWlJ3YWlBOzE7dG90YW
xfaGl0czoxOw==
'
```

Notice that while the first request to open the scroll was to `/my_index/_search`, the second request to read the data was to `/_search/scroll`. Each time you call that, passing the `?scroll=1m` querystring, it refreshes the timeout before the scroll is automatically closed.

There are two more things to be aware of:

1. The `size` you pass when opening the scroll applies to each shard, so you will get `size` multiplied by the number of shards in your index on each request.
2. Each request to `/_search/scroll` will return a new `scroll_id` which you must pass on the next call to get the next batch of results. You can't just keep calling with the same `scroll_id`.

It is complete when no hits are returned in the scroll request.

Comment: Thanks! So something like this should work?                                          scroll_id= http get http://MY-OLD-ES.com:9200/my_index/_search?scroll=1m&search_type=scan&size=10;
while $scroll_id; do
$scroll_id = http 'http://MY-OLD-ES.com:9200/_search/scroll?scroll=1m' -d '
SCROLLIDSTRING
'| jq   .hits.hits[] -c | while read x; do id="`echo "$x" | jq -r ._id`"; index="`echo "$x" | jq -r ._index`"; type="`echo "$x" | jq -r ._type`"; doc="`echo "$x" | jq ._source`"; http put "localhost:9200/junk-$index/$type/$id" <<<"$doc"; done;
done

Comment: I'm not gonna lie, bash scripting isn't a strong point for me, but I hope this set you on the right track :) If it helped I would appreciate if you mark it as the correct answer!